# Center User Location with Button - MapKit

Tags: swift, location, swiftui, mapkit, mkmapview

I've been trying to make a button that will zoom/center to the users location when selected which seems to work once only. I would like the button to work regardless the mapType selected. when the button was selected I could set the userTrackingMode back to .none and it would allow me to select the button again to center but if I changed to hybrid or satellite it wouldn't work. I also don't want it to center to the users location based on mapType selection it should retain the current view.

Can someone please review and assist if possible?

ContentView.swift

```
struct MapTypeSelect {
    var title: String
    var map: MKMapType
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var selectedSegment = 0
    @State private var mapSelect = [MapTypeSelect(title: "Standard", map: .standard), MapTypeSelect(title: "Satellite", map: .satellite), MapTypeSelect(title: "Hybrid", map: .hybrid)]
    @State private var userTrackingMode: MKUserTrackingMode = .none


    var body: some View {

    ZStack {
        VStack {
            VStack {

            HStack {
                Picker(selection: $selectedSegment, label: EmptyView()) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< mapSelect.count) {
                        Text(self.mapSelect[$0].title).tag($0)
                    }
                }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            }
        }
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                MapView(mapType: mapSelect[selectedSegment].map, userTrackingMode: $userTrackingMode)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                }

                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: { self.followUser() }) {
                        Image(systemName: "location.fill")
                            .modifier(MapButton(backgroundColor: .primary))
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 500)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


private func followUser() {

     userTrackingMode = .follow

    }
}


fileprivate struct MapButton: ViewModifier {

    let backgroundColor: Color
    var fontColor: Color = Color(UIColor.systemBackground)

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .padding()
            .background(self.backgroundColor.opacity(0.8))
            .foregroundColor(self.fontColor)
            .font(.callout)
            .clipShape(Circle())
    }
}
```

MapView.swift

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {

    var mapType: MKMapType

    var locationManager : CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var userTrackingMode: Binding<MKUserTrackingMode>

    let map = MKMapView(frame: .zero)


    func makeCoordinator() -> MapViewCoordinator {
        MapViewCoordinator(self)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
      map.showsUserLocation = (status == .authorizedAlways)

    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView{


        map.mapType = mapType
        map.showsScale = true
        map.showsTraffic = true
        map.showsCompass = true
        map.showsUserLocation = true
        map.userTrackingMode = .follow
        map.showsBuildings = true


        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.3561, longitude: 151.3694)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, latitudinalMeters: 50000, longitudinalMeters: 50000)

        map.setCameraBoundary(
          MKMapView.CameraBoundary(coordinateRegion: region),
          animated: true)

        let zoomRange = MKMapView.CameraZoomRange(maxCenterCoordinateDistance: 200000)
        map.setCameraZoomRange(zoomRange, animated: true)
        map.region = region


        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        setupLocationManager()

        map.register(
            ArtworkView.self,
        forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier:
          MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)


        loadInitialData()
        map.addAnnotations(artworks)

        return map

    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context){
         if let userLocation = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
            let viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: userLocation, latitudinalMeters: 10000, longitudinalMeters: 10000)
            map.setRegion(viewRegion, animated: true)
        }

        view.delegate = context.coordinator
        view.addAnnotations(artworks)
        view.mapType = self.mapType

    }

    func setupLocationManager() {

        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true
    }

}

var artworks: [Artwork] = []

  private func loadInitialData() {

    // 1
    guard
      let fileName = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "PublicArt", withExtension: "geojson"),
      let artworkData = try? Data(contentsOf: fileName)
      else {
        return
    }

    do {
      // 2
      let features = try MKGeoJSONDecoder()
        .decode(artworkData)
        .compactMap { $0 as? MKGeoJSONFeature }
      // 3
      let validWorks = features.compactMap(Artwork.init)
      // 4
      artworks.append(contentsOf: validWorks)
    } catch {
      // 5
      print("Unexpected error: \(error).")
    }
  }
```